# Самое ближайшее - правильно ли?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Нередко на сайтах, где есть система он-лайн консультаций можно прочитать такую надпись: "Пришлите нам вопрос, и мы ответим вам в самое ближайшее время".
Мне кажется, что нельзя говорить "самое ближайшее", ведь "ближайшее" - это и так превосходная степень прилагательного. Или же тут "самое" просто эмоционально усиливает обещание позвонить как можно скорее?
Одним словом, допустимо ли употребление выражения "самое ближайшее время"?

Answer (score 3):

"Возьми самый ближайший к кому-либо стул", - это безусловно плеоназм, так как ближайший стул - это уже самый близкий к кому-либо, следовательно "самый" здесь избыточно.

А вот самого близкого к кому-либо времени не существует, поэтому "самый" здесь не избыточно. Если заменить синонимами, то "в ближайшее время" - это *в порядке очереди*, а "в самое ближайшее аремя" - *в первую очередь*.

Comment: >А вот самого близкого к кому-либо времени не существует,  
  
Спорно. Зависит от того, как человек себе вообще время представляет. Физики-математики хорошо это понимают. Но это к слову.  
  
Лично я бы сказал, что если "самых близких времен" много, то у них есть и самое ближайшее. А иначе - избыточно.

Comment: @behemothus, историки тоже понимают, что по временной шкале Новейшее самое близкое к нам время, а вот Новое уже подальше от нас находится, но в контексте вопроса, подобные тонкости, по-моему излишни.

Answer (score 2):

Не только допустимо, но и абсолютно верно, потому что "В самое ближайшее время" - фразеологизм, отсюда нельзя убрать САМОЕ, не изменив смысла, что и показал [[@Марк Из](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7)](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7).

Comment: Интересно, а почему фразеологизм?

Самое  ближайшее окружение [Президента].
Самые ближайшие планы.
Самые ближайшие рейсы.

Comment: "Самое ближайшее окружение. Самые ближайшие планы. Самые ближайшие рейсы."-ошибки, их нет в словарях, а "в самое ближайшее время" есть в словаре синонимов и в словаре английских идиом ( http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/eng_rus/30071/%D0%B2). Иногда экспрессивные выражения из народной речи, не всегда грамотные, закрепляются в языке в виде фразеологизма, потому что вносят что-то новое в уже известное и они всем понятны.

Answer (score 2):

Такая грамматика не всем нравится, например: http://filolingvia.com/publ/81-1-0-3193

"Если простую и составную степени объединить, выходят конструкции довольно уродливые. Свежих примеров – сколько угодно. Начнем с элитного. «В самое кратчайшее время», - сказал российский премьер В.В.Путин в своем выступлении 4 декабря 2008 года. Также: «Сегодня самые сильнейшие встретятся с самыми известнейшими».«Желаем вам всего самого наилучшего!». «…О тех законах, которые в самое ближайшее время должны быть приняты».

Смешение простой и составной превосходной степени - это такая старая и распространенная ошибка, что еще в комментариях к официальной кинохронике времен Великой Отечественной войны можно было слышать: «Киев – один из самых старейших городов Украины». «Эта деревня была самой ближайшей к городу». «Он увлекся романами, не пренебрегая и самыми глупейшими»"

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

1) Превосходная степень прилагательного может быть СЕМАНТИЧЕСКИ НЕТОЧНА. Известнейший, сильнейший, ближайший глупейший - эти предметы должны быть ЕДИНСТВЕННЫМИ в своем роде, а в действительности это ряд предметов, их которого можно выбрать "самого". Поэтому делаем вывод: такие выражения возможны, если превосходная степень обладает не абсолютным, а условным значением. Если мы говорим "ближайшие дома" (мн.ч.), то можно сказать "самый ближайший дом".

2) Интересна статистика употребления выражения "в ближайшее время", приведенная в Нацкорпусе: Всего документов - 250, до 1900 года - 0 документов, до 1950 года - 19 документов, до 1990 года - 50 документов. Вот такое развитие языка.

А вот еще примеры:

«Всякий день, ― говорит он, ― благодарю я Бога за то, что он определил мне быть поселянином, которого состояние есть самое ближайшее к натуре и, следственно, самое счастливейшее» (Карамзин).

Прежде всего, как за самое ближайшее и общедоступное от скуки средство, взялся он за пьянство (Г.И. Успенский).

Comment: Не согласен с вами. "Желаю самого наилучшего" – это устойчивое словосочетание, которое так же "ошибочно", как "вокруг да около" и прочие.

 Грамматически, возможно, и неправильна конструкция "самый + превосходная степень прилагательного", то есть в литературном языке нежелательна, но она имеет определённый оттенок, который простому человеку понятен. Мне кажется, что это связано с двумя вещами. Во-первых, часто говорят "лучшие", "ближайшие" и так далее, раз их несколько, то один из них должен быть "самый".

Comment: Во-вторых, конструкция с "самый" звучит несколько "превосходнее", чем превосходная степень, образованная суффиксом. Если "красивейший" часто понимается как "очень красивый" (красивейший пейзаж, например), то "самый красивый" имеет уже совершенно иное значение – это констатация некоторого факта.

Comment: Я не то чтобы против таких выражений, но меня интересует, насколько такая грамматика является разрешенной и как к ним относится наша академическая наука.

Answer (score 2):

А как вы себе представляете подобную конструкцию без превосходной степени? "Мы ответим вам в близкое время"? Вряд ли. Тут уместно выглядит лишь "ближайшее время", то есть превосходная степень, образованная с помощью суффикса, выполняет роль обычного прилагательного и смысл высказывания сводится к "Мы ответим скоро". А вот превосходная степень в данном контексте будет именно что "самое ближайшее", то есть "очень скоро", "в первую очередь", "так быстро, как сможем".

Comment: >А как вы себе представляете подобную конструкцию без превосходной степени?  
  
"Ближайшее"  в современной русском и есть превосходная степень. В стародавние времена означало сравнительную - что отчасти сохранилось и иногда вводит людей в заблуждение.    
Превосходной степени не было вовсе, иногда использовалась конструкция по типу "самый близкий".  Но это такая древность...

Comment: **behemothus**, я о том и толкую, что здесь просто нельзя сформулировать предложение иначе, потому и семантика несколько размывается: вместо того, чтобы передавать превосходную степень ("настолько быстро, насколько возможно"), передаёт просто значение "скоро, быстро".

Answer (score 2):

С прилагательными-причастиями типа ЛЮБИМЫЙ с размытой семантикой (тот, кого любят, или наилюбимейший?) употребление составной формы превосходной степени инода необходимо для понимания смысла фразы: самый любимый.

Устойчивые выражения с ошибкой (их, к счастью, мало;они стали таковыми в результате прочного закрепления ошибки в речи) - что делать, пусть живут, раз позволили закрепить.

Но всё-таки недопустимо безответственное, безграмотное употребление форм степеней сравнения. Правильно: ВСЕГО наилучшего (всего хорошего), а НЕ всего САМОГО наилучшего; В БЛИЖАЙШЕЕ ВРЕМЯ, а БЛИЖАЙШИЙ дом пусть останется домом, стоящим ближе всех прочих домов.

***Выражение "самое ближайшее время"*** ошибочно.

***В ближайшее время** -
в (обозримом, недалеком, ближайшем, близком) будущем, в **(самом непродолжительном, скором) времени**, это вопрос дней, днями, конец виден, не сегодня завтра, остались считанные часы, на (этих) днях, вопрос дней, не за горами, скоро, сейчас, остались считанные дни, со дня на день, вот-вот, оглянуться не успеешь, немедленно. [Здесь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/13250/%D0%B2)*

Answer (score 1):

Что делать человеку, жаждущему выразить свою максимальную заинтересованность, усилить эмоцию, пожелание? - Создать степень, превосходящую превосходную. А ещё лучше - наипревосходнейшую: "...в самое **наиближайшее** время!" Человек - это не просто информационная система, а информационно-эмоционально-чувственная система. Кто-то хочет искренне выражать свои чувства посредством таких пожеланий как: "желаю всего самого наилучшего!" А кто-то хочет играть на чужих эмоциях, управлять ими, например политики, обещая: "...в самое кратчайшее время!" Можно ли их в этом упрекать (я имею в виду и тех и других)?

Comment: Звезда  - суперзвезда - супермегазвезда?))) Вы правы, Сашка-далеко-не-дурак!

Answer (score 1):

"В самое ближайшее..." - это, безусловно, плеоназм, и имеет смысл "самое близкое из самого близкого", что является аналогом "масла масляного".   Из этой же серии выражения "самый первый", "в самом центре", "самый максимальный", "самый оптимальный", и т.д.   "ПЕРВЫЙ" МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ТОЛЬКО ОДИН; и "ближайшее (самое близкое)", и "центр", и "максимальный" может быть только единственное.  Если допустить, что может быть "самое ближайшее", то, по логике, возможно и "не самое ближайшее", "не самый центр" (это уже не будет центр), "менее/более ближайшее", или "менее/более максимальное", что является абсолютно "безграмотной безграмотностью" и "глупой глупостью".  Чувство языка - такой же врождённый дар, как и музыкальный слух, даётся не каждому, поэтому и гуляют такие вот выражения.  Или, например, словосочетание "... как бы ...", втыкаемое во все щели троечниками всех мастей; непонимание в употреблении "так же" и "также", "то же" и "тоже", и т.п., а также главное "недоразумение сезона" - фраза "почему БЫ И нет?". Уверен, что тут же налетят защитники этого безграмотья.  Хочу посмотреть!

Comment: Почему нет? "В самом центре Москвы" — центр большой (в пределах Садового кольца), а это в самом центре. Ну и просто как усиление для придания выразительности.

Comment: Да, я согласен с Вами - в таком контексте это понятие имеет право на жизнь, т.к. не имеется ввиду центр круга. Безусловно, человеку свойственны и эмоции, и чувства, но только для того и существуют правила грамматики, чтобы он выражал свои эмоции грамотно. А если господа-филологи пустят этот процесс на самотёк, то, в финале, дойдём до схемы "как сышыца, так и пишыца"; а до этого уже не далеко.