# Обособление громоздких определений

Tags: запятые

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108. (Там 4-й подпункт 2-го пункта.)

Почему надо про кружок пример без запятой писать, а, например, здесь писать с ней?

> В колледже, самом близжайшем к моему домище, живёт Елизавета-мисс.

Comment: Там во 2-м 4-й подпункт.

Comment: Кстати, Лео, что скажете насчет моего ответа к вашему вопросу насчет слова _ограничен(н)ны_?

Comment: Леопольд, а скажите, откуда это предложение, пожалуйста?

Comment: От себя. Я считаю, надо писать *ограниченны*.

Comment: Леопольд, пока что это, наверное, выигрывающий вариант. Задал вопрос Грамота по этому поводу, а то я до сих пор не уверен. Решим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*В коллЕдже, //самом близком **к моему домище,** // живёт Елизавета-мИсс.*

1. Обособляется определительный оборот, стоящий **после** определяемого слова (по **основному** правилу).

Определительный оборот строится на основе прилагательного в превосходной степени (**самый близкий**).

**Нет оснований** для необособления оборота: два ударения, **нет перехода** ударения на оборот.

2. **Сравнить:**

(1) *В кружке **самом блИзком к невесте** // были её две сестрЫ* (Л. Т.).

(2) *В колледже **самом блИзком ко мне** // живет Елизавета-мИсс.*

**Распространенность** оборота влияет **на расстановку** ударений  и обособление. Возможность обособления определяется **по структуре** предложения.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

**[О сочетании "самый ближайший"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40767/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8)**

**[Как образуются степени прилагательного](https://vk.com/wall-180918617_33)**

Answer (score 0):

Предложение построено неверно. Должно быть так: *самом близком*. Либо так: *ближайжшем*. Нужно выбрать либо составную превосходную, либо простую превосходную, но две сразу использовать нельзя.

*В колледже самом близком к моему домище живёт Елизавета-мисс* — не обособляется, т. к. форма превосходной степени **сложная**; предыдущего определения нет, поэтому обособлять с целью уточнить не получится.

*В колледже, ближайшем к моему домище, живёт Елизавета-мисс* — здесь обособить можно, поскольку форма степени **не сложная**.