# Самое ближайшее время — это фразеологизм или что?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, степени-прилагательных

Вопрос по теме, которая обсуждалась  **[на форуме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40767/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8).**

Тогда были **очень разные мнения**, но меня заинтересовало вот что. Это выражение можно встретить **в [Учебном фразеологическом словаре](https://phraseologiya.academic.ru/935/%D1%81_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%83_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81):**

**с часу на час**

Разг. Неизм. **В самое ближайшее время**, в ближайший момент (о чем-либо ожидаемом). С глаг. несов. и сов. вида: увеличиваться, ждать, ожидать, прибыть… когда? с часу на час.

Как же так? Грамматика считается **некорректной** (превосходная степень так не образуется), но это выражение используют сами **лингвисты.**

Как это **можно оценить?**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

А почему **нельзя узаконить** такую степень? Пусть будет **усиленная превосходная степень,** допускается в разговорной речи.  Кстати, **классики использовали** такую форму, она им не казалась тавтологией.

Comment: Нет, это просто языковой штамп. Фразеологизмом и образностью тут не пахнет.

Comment: Пусть штамп. Но он правильный по грамматике или нет?  Зачем нам штамп, да еще неправильный?  Фразеологизмом его назвали на форуме (по ссылке).  Что меня и заинтересовало.

Comment: Некорректность не определяет образ, фразеологический образ определяет нехарактерное но всё же яркое сочетание, допустимое. А тут просто слово момент заменено синонимом время. А штамп "самое ближайшее" - тавтология по сути, логическая, речевая ошибка. В ближайший момент времени - должно быть.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш комментарий, хорошо бы его преобразовать в ответ) А в словаре ошибка?  (Логическая речевая ошибка зафиксирована в грамматике, этого достаточно.)  Интересно, как пользователи оценивают "ошибку", Форум давний, а сейчас?

Comment: не могу знать, я не отвечаю за всех пользователей форума)

Comment: А за себя (как пользователя языка)  отвечаете?)

Comment: за себя пытаюсь... за свой базар)

Answer (score 1):

Фраза является штампом - то есть повторением легко запоминающегося словосочетания, однако запоминается оно не ввиду фразеологической образности, а ввиду некорректности употребления слов, а именно:

**Самый ближайший** - логическая тавтология, речевая ошибка.

Замечу, что в фразеологизмах, не смотря на необычность сочетания слов, речевых ошибок нет, а наоборот проявлен творческих подход к употреблению слов.

Далее вторая неточность - ближайшее *время*. Даже если время это стихия, как скажем вода, то сочетания вроде быстрая вода~быстрое время - явно не дают хороших сочетаний. Время стихия - но только в очень переносном смысле. Беспокойное время...

Так что ближайшее (физическая характеристика) не корректно, к такой абстракции как время, нужно другое слово, обозначающие временной промежуток - момент, час...

В ближайший момент времени, в самый близкий момент времени - так могло бы быть корректно.

А в ближайшее время и тем более самое ближайшее время - это просто мем, мемас, мемасик, то есть криво составленная идиома, а никакой не фразеологизм. И соглашусь с тем, что фраза эмоциональная, что тоже характерно для мемов. То есть вроде как обещание "буду стараться успеть", но без обещания, а креативненько воздействуя на собеседника, чтобы собеседник подумал, но на самом деле никакого уточнения когда будет это "самое ближайшее время", либо как будет прилагаться усилие, для достижения этого "самого ближайшего времени" - никак не уточняется. Тем самым дает пространство для манёвра исполнителю...

*Фантазии:
Возможно, "самое ближайшее время" - это такое время, когда заказчик еще не разочаровался в ожидании "самого ближайшего времени". Исполнитель держит непрерывную коммуникационную связь с заказчиком, и как только он почувствует раздражение заказчика, по поводу того, не наступило ли то "самое ближайшее время уже-сь"? (а почувствовать он может в том случае, когда заказчик таки спросит еще раз, ну когда мол..) вот в тот самый момент и наступит то "самое ближайшее время" и этот момент будет продолжаться до тех пор, пока исполнитель не сделает, что обещал. Хотя исполнитель может и сделать раньше положенного "самого ближайшего времени", чем очень удивит заказчика и обрадует. Тут главное, чтобы не получилось как в мультике про стрижку, которая только начата...*

Дело в том, что путают фразеологизмы и идиомы. Фразеологизмы, это яркие образные выражения, а идиомы - это просто логичные или нелогичные сочетания слов, если логичные - это всякие максимы или афоризмы, а нелогичные - мемчики.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149906/discussion-on-answer-by---------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.